# Android : restart the service

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

My application have a Service that every X minutes do same action on the database than it stopSelf() and into onDestroy method I have palced this code for restart the service after same time:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Intent intent_service = new Intent(context,vampireService.class);
    PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent_service,0);
    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()+ 4500000, pintent);
}
```

But I don't understand why if my phone go in sleep mode the service not restart ! Appears that the count time of AlarmManager to start when I power back up the display....it's possibile ? If yes, how can I resolve this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [ELAPSED_REALTIME](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME)...

> **This alarm does not wake the device up**; if it goes off while the device is asleep, it will not be delivered until the next time the device wakes up.

Try using [ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP) to see if that helps (not sure if it will work for a service however).

Comment: no don't work...but than How can stop and restard a service after XXX time ??

Comment: @Mimmo: The solution provided in this answer should work fine. However, you will not get reliable results with a `getService()` `PendingIntent` and a `_WAKEUP` alarm. Moreover, your service will need to maintain a `WakeLock` while it is operating, or else the device will fall back asleep. You might consider using my [`WakefulIntentService`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-wakeful), as it has the proper pattern for using `_WAKEUP` alarms and keeping the device awake while the work is going on.

Comment: But it's possibile that one service can't restart when the phone is in sleep mode ?

Answer (score 0):

You can (and should) schedule your Service to run every X time, using the Alarm Manager.  You have this option of setRepeating.